# dicom applet viewer

Tags: java, applet, dicom, appletviewer

I am looking for an opensource appletviewer.Idea is using Java webstart i want to download the appletviewer (with the help of JNLP config) along with the specific dicom file [dynamic content w.r.t user/patient] in my webapplication,so that end users will have access to see their dicom files in web application.

If anyone have come across on this kindly let me know.
Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 2):

As part of his [PixelMed DICOM Java Toolkit](http://pixelmed.com/), David Clunie has developed a number of [demo applets](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/webstart/), among these a DICOM Image Viewer for which the JNLP file can be accessed from [here](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/webstart/DicomImageViewer.html). PixelMed Java DICOM Toolkit and its sub-components are available under a BSD license.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Weasis](http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/WEA/Home)?

It is a Java web start based viewer. We use it on Linux and Windows workstations and I find it to be an excellent lightweight Dicom viewer.